# Python how to edit/update a GitHub gist?

Tags: python, api, http, github, gist

I am trying to update a already created json file in a gist from a python program. The problem is, I can't figure out how to do it.

I've found [this api](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/gists#update-a-gist), which I'm pretty sure is related to what I'm trying to do.
I once again don't know how to use it properly though.

Also I found a wrapper for GitHub gists called "[simplegists](https://github.com/softvar/simplegist)" that looked perfect for what I'm trying to do. However, it seems to be currently broken, and I and others are having problems using it( specifically [this problem](https://github.com/softvar/simplegist/issues/8) ).

Would anyone be kind enough to help me figure out how I can edit a gist using a GitHub authentication token, in python, or at least give me some kind of reference I can work off of? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite some python wrappers aren't working anymore because Github [discontinued](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-username-and-password) password authentication to the API on November 13, 2020. The best way to proceed is by using an API token.
So first [get a token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new) and select the relevant scopes ('gist').

Then you can use a python patch request in line with the [API description](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/gists#update-a-gist) to update your gist with the new json file:

```
import requests
import json

token='API_TOKEN'
filename="YOUR_UPDATED_JSON_FILE.json"
gist_id="GIST_ID"

content=open(filename, 'r').read()
headers = {'Authorization': f'token {token}'}
r = requests.patch('https://api.github.com/gists/' + gist_id, data=json.dumps({'files':{filename:{"content":content}}}),headers=headers) 
print(r.json())
```

Note that this example assumes that you haven't enabled [two-factor authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#working-with-two-factor-authentication).

Answer (score 2):

In GitHub REST API Version `2022-11-28`, you need to change
`headers = {'Authorization': f'token {token}'}`
to
`headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}`